# List of hosts on which a directory exists via ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to check if a directory exist or not in a server.

If the directory exist, I want to get the hostname of the server.

I want something like this but with ansible

```bash
if [-d /directory]; then
  echo $server_hostname
else
  exit 0
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html

Answer (score 2):

Simple playbook for this

```yaml
- name: Disrectory exists
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Task name
    stat:
      path: [path to the file or directory you want to check]
    register: register_dir

  - name: Task name
    debug:
      msg: "The file or directory exists on {{ ansible_hostname }}"
    when: register_dir.stat.exists
```